# TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString error while executing powershell command in java

Tags: java, powershell

```
String cd = "";
    String file="E:/Code.java";
    cd+="powershell\n";
    cd+="$username=\"mail@gmail.com”;\n";
    cd+="$password=”pwd”;\n";
    cd+="$smtpServer = “smtp.gmail.com”;\n";
    cd+="$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;\n";
    cd+="$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer,587);\n";
    cd+="$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(\"mail@gmail.com\", \"password\");\n";
    cd+="$smtp.EnableSsl = $true;\n";
    cd+="$msg.From = \"mail@gmail\";\n";
    cd+="$msg.To.Add(“mail@gmail.com”);\n";
    cd+="$msg.Body=”Your message Body”;\n";
    cd+="$msg.Subject = “"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"”;\n";
    cd+="$file=“"+file+"”;\n";
    cd+="$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file);\n";
    cd+="$msg.Attachments.Add($att);\n";
    cd+="$smtp.Send($msg);";
    String line;

    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cd);
     System.out.println("Standard Error:");
      BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getErrorStream()));
      while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
      }
      stderr.close();

    System.out.println("Done");
```

The output is :

---

Standard Error:
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Done

Comment: `“` and `”` aren't ASCII doublequotes. Use an escaped doublequote `"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the code with Notepad++

See the encoding type.

It seems that the quotes are ASCII quotes. Try using the backtick symbol followed by the double quotes like :

> `"